# Understanding ListT and Monad Transformers in Scala

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz, monad-transformers

We know how to compose functions `X => M[Y]`, where `M` is a monad, with `>=>`.

For example if I have functions `getOrders():List[Order]` and `getOrderItems(order: Order):List[OrderItem]` I can easily compose them to get `getAllOrderItems: List[OrderItem]`

```
val getAllOrderItems = getOrders >=> getOrderItems
```

This composition works *iff* `List` is a monad and provides `flatMap[B](f: A => List[B])`

Suppose both functions `getOrder` and `getOrderItems` return `Option[List]` rather than `List`. Can we still compose those functions with `>=>` ?  No, since there is no `flatMap` for `Option[List]`.

In order to compose  `getOrder` and `getOrderItems` we have to write a *wrapper* `ListT`, which wraps `Option[List]` (and any `M[List]` where `M` is a monad) and provides `flatMap`. Now we can redefine the functions to return `ListT` and then compose those functions with `>=>` as we used to.

Does it make sense ?

Comment: Maybe i didn't get something, but if `getOrders` returns `List[Order]`  you can't write `getOrders >=> getOrderItems` and get a result of type  `List[OrderItem]`, cause `getOrders` returns a list or order whereas `getOrderItems` expects an order, at least it should return a `List[List[OrderItem]]`

Comment: @AlexIv `>=>` is not just a _simple_ composition.  It _flattens_ `List[List[OrderItem]]` (and it is possible only because `List` has _flatten_)

Comment: `>=>` is a Kleisli arrow, it's simply an alias for `andThen` operation, so it can't flatten anything. I guess that you confused it with monadic bind operation (`>>=`), which is used in its implementation: `kleisli((a: A) => b.bind(this(a))(k(_)))`

Comment: @AlexIv Let's check it with REPL :)) Could you try the following in REPL: `val f = Kleisli { (x: Int) => (x + 1).some };  val g = Kleisli { (x: Int) => (x * 100).some }; f >=> g`  and post the result here ?

Comment: You r write, my mistake came from my implementation for Kleisli for `getOrderItems`.

Comment: But still i can't understand why your `getOrders >=> getOrderItems` works, it might work with bind operation and yes the result would be `getAllOrderItems: List[OrderItem]`, but `>=>` is at least a function composition so it should return a function or in this case a Kleisli function.

Comment: Type of `getAllOrderItems` is `() => List[OrderItem]`